# PHP Concatenation for displaying from the db

Tags: php, concatenation

How do I make this line of code work?

```
    echo $row['Headings'.'&nbsp;'.'Contents']; //
```

I want to display what's in the 'Headings' column from the database, then a page break, then what's in the 'Contents' column in the db. Please help.

Comment: Can you post your database query that you have coded in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $row['Headings'] .'<br />'. $row['Contents'];
```

Comment: @Callie where is &nbsp; on this answer?

Comment: @ASR: `<br>` not a "page break" either.

Comment: @zerkms in this case yes. If you men that, page break on Webpage should be pagination.

Comment: As I wanted to do some styling as well, the final line ended up being this: `echo "<strong>".$row['Headings']."</strong><br /><p>" . $row['Contents']."</p>";`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $row['headings'] . '&nbsp' . $row['contents'];
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
echo $row['Headings'];
echo '<br />'; 
echo $row['Contents'];
```

Comment: '&nbsp;' is used for non breakable space. For giving line break use '<br />'

Answer (score 0):

Set glue

```
$glue = "<br />"; // or even what you want
```

Store it in one variable

```
$variable  = $row['Headings'];
$variable .= $glue;
$variable .= $row['Contents'];
```

== OR implode by Array ==

```
$variable  = implode($glue, Array($row['Headings'], $row['Contents']));
```

And then display

```
echo $variable;
```

Comment: As he noticed in question, he wants `page break` which is in this case new line.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
echo "{$row['Headings']}<br />{$row['Contents']}";
```

Or the way I should do it

```
$headings = $row['Headings'];
$contents = $row['Contents'];

echo $headings.'<br />'.$contents
```

Comment: Why do he Need to create temp variable? It is stored in `$row` array

Comment: @M1K1O I said I will do it like my second solution because when you change something in your database or code you will only replace it on one place. If you use for example 20 times $row['Contents']; in your code and your table header changes from Contents to Content you should change it 20 times, with my second solution just one time.

Comment: @Callie: if you alter a table you can always use an alias in a select. PS: it's `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as :
`$result = mysql_query('select concat(Headings, Contents) as final_string from table_name');

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo $row['final_string'];
}`
Please correct me if I am wrong.